# Excel format currency EUR

Tags: excel, format, phpexcel, currency

I can't find how to format text to currency like that : **7.075,21 €** (7 thousand seventy five euros and twenty one "centimes").

If I do **#.##0,0 €** I have "**########**" in my cell, then I have to double-click+enter to have the value and it is like 1202.98600 € (**the "," is missing, "." is not on the right place and there is too much numbers**)

hello, help please :)

Comment: check your regional settings.  sounds like you have `.` set as your decimal separator when you want `,` as the decimal separator.

Comment: Yes thx, but my question is **HOW** to modify that with **PhpExcel**

Answer (score 0):

Number format masks should use  `,` as the thousands separator, and `.` as the decimals separator. MS Excel itself will interpret these "locale-aware" when it displays the value